# Breaks in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been reading Wickham's http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/scale_identity.html guide. I understand that scale_identity function uses the value contained in the variable to do the scaling. However, I am not quite sure what "breaks = df$colour" does here.

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:4,
  y = 1:4,
  colour = c("red", "green", "blue", "yellow")
)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = colour)) +
  scale_fill_identity("trt", labels = letters[1:4], breaks = df$colour, guide = "legend")
```

I am a beginner and am struggling with ggplot2. I have bought Wickham's ggplot2 book and reading it. So, I thought of asking about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example, the user just wanted to change the names of the colors in the legend. Each value color value in the data.frame is used as the fill color thanks to `scale_fill_identity` but in order to match up the colors to labels, it's safest to give the labels and breaks, the latter are the actually values used for the fill, and the former are how you want them described in the legend. So you are matching up

```
labels = c("a","b","c","d"),
breaks = c("red", "green", "blue", "yellow")
```

where the values at each position are matched up.

[image]

Comment: Thanks MrFlick. What does "breaks" mean? Sometimes I hear it's similar to the tick marks (or the label on the axes), and now I am hearing it's the color inside the legend. I'm really confused. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: It doesn't have one definition. It's used more often with continuous variables to turn them into categorical variables. It's basically where values along some range change. It doesn't really matter what it's named.